# Large Postgres data size to handle with google data studio

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, size, looker-studio

I have remote access to a distant Postgres Server containing a database which size is almost 50 Go.

Is there any method to work on it with Google Data Studio without downloading the whole 50 Go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the native PostGres connector in Data Studio, it does not pull all data from the database server. Rather, it will construct separate aggregate queries for each chart element and push down the queries to the database server.

For example, let's assume you have sales data by product and by day in your database. If you draw a chart that shows only current months total sales by product, Data Studio will create a SQL query with `WHERE` clause that limits dates to current month and also add a `GROUP BY` clause for the products. Thus, Data Studio will only get back the aggregated results. This will be transparent to the dashboard owner and the viewer.

Keep this in mind while designing your dashboard and make sure to put in filters and aggregations to limit the amount of data you are pulling from the database.